# A JavaScript error occured in the main process : Compass

Tags: mongodb

When I started mongoDB client application Compass 1.13.1, I get the error like: [image]

How I can solve it? Same issue was [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1165).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

1. Go to task manager
2. Kill the process called: "The MongoDB GUI"

Comment: You should also disconnect. That should prevent this error message. Don't click the "X" straight away.

Comment: In my case the process name was "MongoDBCompassCommunity". So look for both.

Comment: After Killing the process, you should also disconnect.

Comment: what a disaster! I have to kill it every time I want to use it?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give me the whole command for the system to work for compass?

Answer (score 6):

### **Stuck?**

open app -> get error -> no reboot ->

task manager -> "The MongoDB GUI" or "MongoDBCompassCommunity" -> kill process

---

### Prevention?

**Never** quit the app using native close methods ("**X**" button / "Close window")

**Always** quit via `Connect -> Quit (Ctrl+Q)`

---

No need to disconnect first. It is just badly done electron app.

---

Answer based on solution from [@Senne Verhaegen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8727780/senne-verhaegen)

Answer (score 1):

### **Here's some additional ways how to solve:**

---

1. From \AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.13.1\resources delete the file named as **app.asar**, before it copy somewhere (in my case was desktop). Then paste file **app.asar** to this path again \AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass\app-1.13.1\resources and rerun Compass.
2. Restart Windows and try to run again Compass.
3. If nothing helps, reinstall the application (another version, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I closed the app without disconnecting.  I tried to start up the program and received the error.  I waited about 30 seconds and then, surprise!  Compass popped up and is running - even though the error showed.  It must have cleaned itself up.  I am using MongoDB Compass 4.0.3 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the process "**The MongoDB GUI**" is still running after the application is closed.

Since I'm a very lazy person to open the Task Manager everytime this happens, I created a `batch` file with the following content:

```
@ECHO OFF
taskkill /f /im MongoDBCompass.exe
%LOCALAPPDATA%\MongoDBCompass\MongoDBCompass.exe
exit
```

I saved this file on the same directory of `MongoDBCompass.exe`, which can be easily found by checking the properties of your MongoDBCompass shortcut.

I overrided the **Target** to use that `.bat` instead of the default `.exe` and just said to it **Run as administrator**, never had problems again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing a recent version of Compass. This problem has been fixed in 1.17.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me:

1. Go to task manager
2. Kill the process called: "Error". It will have a mongodb icon